# An identitiy for hyperbolic functions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Let $y$ be a paramater and $f(x)=\frac{\sinh(xy)}{x\sinh y}$. The question is $f^{\prime}(3)=?$ I find the answer as $$f^{\prime}(3)=\frac{3y\cosh(3y)-\sinh(3y)}{9\sinh y}.$$

But the answer of book is $$f^{\prime}(3)=\coth (3y)- \frac{1}{3 y}.$$

I can not see the identity (if it is true)

$$\frac{3y\cosh(3y)-\sinh(3y)}{9\sinh y}=\coth (3y)- \frac{1}{3 y}.$$

Comment: It isn't true.  Set $y=1$ and compare the values.  Not even close.

Comment: There is probably a typo - in your solution or in the book. Simple exchange $y$ to $x$ (or vice versa) in one denominator makes them equal.

Comment: I do not really believe that both answers are correct. It looks like that you've evaluated first derivative but not the third. And the answer in your book seems to be too "simple" for the value of the third derivative

Comment: @MikalaiParshutsichYou are right. I had made a typo. I edit the question.